# How to log only 2 levels with one appender?

Tags: logging, log4j2

I have a log4j2 configuration that logs to console only those entries whose level is `ERROR`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="${sys:logFilename}" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Instead I want to log to console both `ERROR` and `INFO` levels, but no other levels. How can I configure that?

Comment: change <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" /> to <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" /> but this will include WARN as well

Comment: @almasshaikh Sorry, but that's not what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 is to ensure that the appender receives all events you want it to log. You have set the root logger to DEBUG, so that part is done. Good.

Step 2 is to filter out all undesired log events for that appender.

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
    <Filters>

        <!-- First deny warn and fatal messages -->
        <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>

        <!-- Then from the remainder, 
             accept info, warn, error, fatal (actually only INFO & ERROR are left)
             and deny debug/trace -->
        <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </Filters>
</Console>
```